# Blender is not working when I start it it crashed in a moment

Tags: error

Hello I am new to OpenFoam and Blender even at Computational Fluid Dynamics. I already install the blender in ubuntu terminal but when I start it , everytime it immediately crashes and shows the following message

```
 ** shared memfd open() failed: Function not implemented
ALSA lib confmisc.c:767:(parse_card) cannot find card '0'

ALSA lib conf.c:4528:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_card_driver returned error: No such file or directory

ALSA lib confmisc.c:392:(snd_func_concat) error evaluating strings

ALSA lib conf.c:4528:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_concat returned error: No such file or directory

ALSA lib confmisc.c:1246:(snd_func_refer) error evaluating name

ALSA lib conf.c:4528:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory

ALSA lib conf.c:5007:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory

ALSA lib pcm.c:2495:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM default

AL lib: (EE) ALCplaybackAlsa_open: Could not open playback device 'default': No such file or directory

Received X11 Error:

        error code:   1

        request code: 143

        minor code:   34

        error text:   BadRequest (invalid request code or no such operation)

Writing: /tmp/blender.crash.txt

Segmentation fault (core dumped) **
```

now after installing pulseaudio error reduces to

** shared memfd open() failed: Function not implemented

shared memfd open() failed: Function not implemented

Received X11 Error:

```
    error code:   1

    request code: 143

    minor code:   34

    error text:   BadRequest (invalid request code or no such operation)
```

Writing: /tmp/blender.crash.txt

Segmentation fault (core dumped) **

Comment: Welcome to Blender.SE. Wich version are you using? Did you tried with other versions?

Comment: Blender  version 2.79

Comment: Using blender in the ubuntu terminal

Comment: and  did not tried any other versions of blender

Comment: Download the version from blender.org